# AS3 String splitting keeping tags

Tags: string, actionscript-3, split

I have variable strings that can contain tags, e.g.:

```
"<b>Water</b>=H<sub>2</sub>O"
```

What i want is an array that should look like:

```
Array[0] <b>Water</b>
Array[1] =H
Array[2] <sub>2</sub>
Array[3] O
```

How can i do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, but i can't see how this can help me with AS3.

Comment: @user3123207 There is a function called `split()`.

Comment: Thanks, i know that function, but with split() you can't keep the delimiters. Or maybe you have an example with a regexp? I tried it, but did not find a functioning one.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go, it uses a common regex to find html tags to get it separated and then indexOf and substring to assemble it back together.

```
function splitWithTags(str:String):Array {

    var tags:Array = str.match(/(<(.|\n)*?>)/g);
    var c:int = tags.length;
    if(c%2 != 0) c--; // if it's odd, decrement to make even so loop works, last tag will be ignored.

    if(c<2) return [str]; // not enough tags so return full string

    var out:Array = [];

    var end:int = 0;
    var pos1:int, pos2:int;

    for(var i:int = 0; i<c; i+=2) {
        // find position of 2 tags.
        pos1 = str.indexOf(tags[i]);
        pos2 = str.indexOf(tags[i+1]);

        if(pos1 >= end+1) { // there's some stuff not between tags to add
            out.push(str.substring(end, pos1));
        }

        end = pos2+tags[i+1].length
        out.push(str.substring(pos1, end));
    }

    if(end < str.length) { // there is substr at end
        out.push(str.substring(end, str.length));
    }

    return out;
}
```

Comment: Hey @user3123207 how did this go? It would be good if you could mark this question as answered if it worked for you. It's how stack overflow works: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work